# How are arguments to user defined functions in R assigned by default?

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to convert nested `for loops` to pure `lapply` calls, as I'm using so far a mixture of both. I'm having trouble to understand how the elements to loop over are defined within `lapply`. To get a basic understanding, I used this very simple code when I tried to imitate the nested `lapply` suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293798

```
testlist4 <- c("hello", "goodbye", "again")
testlist5 <- c("winter", "summer")


lapply(testlist4, function(d){ lapply(testlist5, function(a,b) {paste0(a, b)}, b=d)})
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "winterhello"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "summerhello"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "wintergoodbye"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "summergoodbye"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "winteragain"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] "summeragain"
```

I understand that `d` is what I defined for the outer `lapply` call and I assume it iterates over the top level list elements. But how does R determine what `a` and `b` could be, does it "guess" or is there a default where it looks first?

Comment: Value and name are two different things, and name is something you can call the value. Besides, `lapply()` will reserve name of variables. If you don't have names for variables,  then the generated output will not have it of course. You can try `lapply(testlist4, function(d){ lapply(testlist2, function(a,b) {paste0(a, b)}, b=d)})` to see how the names are kept.

Comment: @MrFlick: ok, maybe I should have left out the part with the names of the list elements. My main question is how R can work with `function(a,b)` if I don't specify what I mean with `a` or `b`. I can imagine how that works if I have one variable, like `d`, but not if R has to guess what the two variables are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` will pass values to the function you specify as an unnamed parameter in the first position to the function . So if I extract the function in your sample

```
foo <- function(a,b) {paste0(a, b)}

lapply(testlist4, function(d){ lapply(testlist5, foo, b=d)})
```

The first time `foo()` is called it will be called with

```
foo("winter", b="hello")
# [1] "winterhello"
```

This is because the inner `lapply` is iterating over `testlist5` so those values will come first by default. You are also passing the value of `d` as the named parameter `b` to this function. If instead you passed that parameter as `a` like

```
lapply(testlist4, function(d){ lapply(testlist5, foo, a=d)})
```

you would instead be calling

```
foo("winter", a="hello")
# [1] "hellowinter"
```

which, by the rules of how named and positional parameters work, would put the "winter" value in the second parameter because that is the slot open that is not named in the call. You can read more about [argument matching in the R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation)